# Combine queries with LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have a two LINQ expressions:

```
var servicesAll = servisesGroup.Services.Where().ToList();
var serviceCompleted =
    servisesGroup.Services.Where(t => t.Events.Any(k => k.IdEventType == 7))
              .ToList();
if (serviceCompleted .Count == servicesAll .Count)
{
    result = true;
}
```

What heppens here:
1. I take all `services` in `service group`.
2. I take all `services` in `service group` with `event type`.
3. And check that all `services` in `services group` have a `event` with this `event type`.

Its possible to check that all `services` in `services group` have an event with `event type = 7` in one query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure there is, use `All` method:

```
return servisesGroup.Services
                    .All(s => s.Events.Any(e => e.IdEventType == 7));
```

Comment: `Where` returns items which met condition. `All` returns `true`/`false` and answers *do all items met condition?* question.